# HSQL upgrade to 1.8: ... DEFAULT 'NaN' changed to ... DEFAULT 0E0/0E0 in database.script causes HsqlException: unexpected token / in HSQL 2.3.2

Tags: upgrade, hsqldb, nan

I have an application using HSQL 1.7.2 that contains table definitions with default values of NaN for some of the DOUBLE columns.  After issuing, with 1.7.2,

```
SET SCRIPTFORMAT TEXT
SHUTDOWN SCRIPT
```

the following appears in the database.script file:

```
CREATE TABLE ... DOUBLE DEFAULT 'NaN' NOT NULL ...
```

I'm attempting to upgrade to HSQL 2.3.2, but I first have to upgrade to 1.8.  I'm finding that after the upgrade to 1.8, the database.script file has:

```
CREATE TABLE ... DOUBLE DEFAULT 0E0/0E0 NOT NULL ...
```

When I open this database with HSQL 2.3.2, I get "SQLException: error in script file line ..." on the line at which "/" first appears.  The traceback includes "Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: /".

I've messed around a lot with `double_nan=false`, without success.

Does anybody have any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 1):

Support for NaN as default value was dropped in version 2.x. This will be restored in the next update.

For the time being, change the default to NULL and add a TRIGGER on the table to convert NULL entries to NaN.

The property `hsqldb.double_nan=false` must be specified or the statement `SET DATABASE SQL DOUBLE NAN FALSE` executed for the database to accept the NaN data values .